# GROUP BY not following ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, distinct, sql-order-by

I need to select the latest three entries in a table for one specific user and with another columns unique value. Here is the structure of my database:

```
time_tracking
    id
    user
    todo
    tracked_time
    start_date
    start_time
    running
```

So the `todo` column must be unique, and I need the three most recent for each `user` ordered by `start_date` and `start_time` descending.

I tried to use `DISTINCT` and many other answers around Google, but none seemed to help.
Using something like

```
SELECT * FROM time_tracking WHERE user = 4735350 GROUP BY todo ORDER BY start_date DESC, start_time DESC LIMIT 3
```

**ALMOST** gets it, but it skips some `todos` if it was in a previous value, like this:

```
id  |user    |todo    |start_date    |start_time
1   |4735350 |1       |2014-09-10    |10:00:00
2   |4735350 |2       |2014-09-11    |10:00:00
3   |4735350 |1       |2014-09-11    |11:00:00 -- gets skipped because of id=1 even though it has a more recent date
```

Edit: I need all columns from the table, so it seems I cannot use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: change select * to select distinct just the fields you need.

Comment: What columns from the data do you need?  distinct will only work if you need only distinct columns.

Comment: I need all columns from the table @MarshallTigerus and @DanBracuk, so I can't use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I don't understand... todo must be unique or not? Because at first you say that yes, but then you say any todo gets skipped... Do you want a unique combination for user-todo?

Comment: `todo` must be unique. What I said at the end is that with that code I posted, some todos that **should** appear are being skipped @carexcer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get maximum start_date value by doing going by and can use EXISTS

[`SQL FIDDLE`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/490cc1/1)

```
SELECT * FROM 
time_tracking t
WHERE user = 4735350 
AND exists
(
SELECT  1
FROM time_tracking 
WHERE user = 4735350 
GROUP BY todo 
HAVING MAX(start_date) = t.start_date
      and MAX(start_time) = t.start_time
)
order by start_date desc, start_time desc
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Tried and it returned two repeated `todo` values, `132496974`, `132496974` and `121049251`.

Comment: @MatheusGrieger, updated having clause to check for max date and time also

Comment: Tried again and it still skipped some lines ): Values returned: `132496744`, `110181083`, `132773311`. Values returned using `SELECT * FROM time_tracking WHERE user = 4735350 ORDER BY start_date DESC, start_time DESC` (repeated removed by myself): `132496974`, `121049251`, `132496744`, `110181083`... So it's not working, as it is not returning the latest three, it's skipping some.

Comment: can you add some more data points to sql fiddle, it was working with sample data here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/490cc1/1

Comment: Updated there with actual values from my table. It worked on `SQL FIDDLE` but did not work within my server, how is that possible?

Comment: @MatheusGrieger, it would have created new sql fiddle url, can you paste that URL as data is changed.

Comment: I guess it's this one: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a7674/1/0). `3929` and `3908` were skipped on my server.

Comment: @MatheusGrieger, you are right, it is working in fiddle, in your server, did you miss any part of the code

Comment: Nope, I copied it exactly as you posted it there. The only differences are the other columns (which are on my first post) but I guess it won't make any difference, since I did not change your code. Also, does your code gets the entry if it is in another date, as the day before? I need that too. The last three, not the last three from the last day...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
SELECT * FROM time_tracking WHERE user = 4735350 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY start_date DESC, start_time DESC LIMIT 3
```

Changing the `group by` from todo to `1`

Edit:
Well, I was trying a new solution but I get to go, but at least, try something like this:

`select t1.*
  from (select todo, MAX(start_date) start_date 
   from time_tracking group by todo
)  t2 join time_tracking t1 on t1.todo = t2.todo and t1.start_date = t2.start_date
order by start_date desc, start_time desc
LIMIT 3;`

Regards.

Comment: Nope, it is giving repeated `todo` values.

Comment: Your second code is repeating the `todo` columns ):

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [user],todo, max(start_time),max(start_date) FROM time_tracking WHERE [user] = 4735350 GROUP BY [user],todo
```

Try this query... Working

Comment: Well those brackets did gave a syntax error, so I removed 'em and tried, and it didn't work as expected, skipped around 10 lines before the first result it returned...